# Basic computations in frequncy domain

Tags: gui-construction, control-systems

I have been trying to find documentation on performing basic operation with transfer function models but have been unable to do so. By basic operation I mean, e.g. Multiply controller transfer function model with existing model or extracting transfer function model from state space models. Even an answer to these questions would be sufficient for me since I have not been able to do them.

I enjoy the symbolic computation aspect of Mathematica but the commands and even the basic operations are not straightforward. If there is any unofficial documentation that covers basic controls operations (SISO and MIMO examples including the basic operations), please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for model manipulations can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ModelConnections.html).

Converting from one model to another is very straightforward. Just do `new[old[...]]`. For example,

```
TransferFunctionModel[StateSpaceModel[{{{a}}, {{b}}}]]
```

> [image]